# RecyclerView's onClick won't work clicking items, only when you click BETWEEN items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm learning Android and I'm testing things with RecyclerView. I wanted to add an OnItemClickListener, I wanted to see if works so I made a Toast appear each time I click on items, but something weird happens, only triggers when I click BETWEEN cards of Recycler, not when I click items. I've been looking for people with the same problem but didn't found anything.

This is the RecyclerAdapter and the Activity for it.

**Adapter**

```
public class CardAdapter extends ListAdapter<Card, CardAdapter.CardHolder> {

    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    private Context mContext;
    private Intent myIntent;

    protected CardAdapter() {

        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
    }

    private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Card> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Card>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(Card oldItem, Card newItem) {
            return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(Card oldItem, Card newItem) {
            return oldItem.getCardImage() == newItem.getCardImage() &&
                    oldItem.getCardName().equals(newItem.getCardName()) &&
                    oldItem.getCardCode().equals(newItem.getCardCode()) &&
                    oldItem.getCardSet().equals(newItem.getCardSet()) &&
                    oldItem.getQuantity() == newItem.getQuantity() &&
                    oldItem.getRarity().equals(newItem.getRarity());

        }
    };

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CardHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        return new CardHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardHolder holder, int position) {
        Card currentCard = getItem(position);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(currentCard.getCardImage()).fit().centerInside().into(holder.cardImage);
        holder.cardName.setText(currentCard.getCardName());
        holder.cardCode.setText(currentCard.getCardCode());
        holder.cardSet.setText(currentCard.getCardSet());
        holder.rarity.setText(currentCard.getRarity());


    }


    class CardHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView cardImage;
        private TextView cardName;
        private TextView cardCode;
        private TextView cardSet;
        private TextView quantity;
        private TextView rarity;

        public CardHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
            cardName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardName);
            cardCode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardCode);
            cardSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardSet);
            rarity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardRarity);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "epaepa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("LogDiaViewHolder","epaepa");

                }
            });
        }

        public ImageView getCardImage() {
            return cardImage;
        }

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Card card);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class CardListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CardViewModel cardViewModel;
    private View decorView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_list);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final CardAdapter adapter = new CardAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        cardViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CardViewModel.class);
        cardViewModel.getAllCards().observe(this, new Observer<List<Card>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Card> cards) {
                adapter.submitList(cards);
            }
        });

        decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                if (visibility == 0) {
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(hideSystemBars());
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(hideSystemBars());
        }
    }

}
```

If someone wants the full project I'll leave repo here: https://github.com/nochuckles/BattleSpiritsCBDB

Any help would be nice, thanks!

Comment: I usually write my clicklistener in the onBindViewHolder method, for your main layout you can do the same.

Comment: I tried, but keeps happening the same, works good but only when I click between items.

Comment: please update your question title to explain precisely what your question is or was

Comment: @chuckles if it is solved considering marking a solution as correct or posting your solution as an answer to help people experiencing the same.

Comment: can you please add your adapter layout in your question.

Comment: also Note : after adding your onClicklistener inside onBindViewHolder, remove itemView.setOnClickListener.

Comment: please update your question title.

Comment: @a_local_nobody to what? I had a problem and it's fixed. What should I say on my title? I'm not trying to be rude, I think the title it's ok but if it's not for some reason I don't know which one.

Comment: change your title to explain what you were struggling with, think of it this way : `if someone else has this problem, what would they google or search for, to find my question`

Comment: I don't think you're rude and i'm not trying to be either, i'm just trying to make sure people in future find your question and your solution :)

Comment: you should look at the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some general tips on how best to use SO , but your question wasn't bad at all, it's simply a matter of making sure people in future can also find it when they google their problem

Comment: good, thank you for changing :D I could have changed it myself, but this way you learn something :) welcome to SO, i'll upvote both your question and your answer, welcome

Comment: @a_local_nobody I think it's okey now, 'between' was a word I used to try to find solutions, so I guess it's good on title. And thanks for the comment edit! I'm not used to SO tools, I'm not used to SO in general yet, I'll try to doing better next time!

Comment: no problem, I'm really not trying to be a pain or rude, it just helps people in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it! Apparently if you have the attribute:

```
clickable:true
```

on your `CardView` this will happen.

I don't know why, I was testing different things and when I removed that, it started to work perfectly. I don't know why this happens, I'll do some research but if someone has some information on this, I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set your OnClickListeners in **BindViewHolder**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardHolder holder, int position) {
        Card currentCard = getItem(position);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(currentCard.getCardImage()).fit().centerInside().into(holder.cardImage);
        holder.cardName.setText(currentCard.getCardName());
        holder.cardCode.setText(currentCard.getCardCode());
        holder.cardSet.setText(currentCard.getCardSet());
        holder.rarity.setText(currentCard.getRarity());

        //example
        holder.cardName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "epaepa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("LogDiaViewHolder","epaepa");

            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not at you adapter to display the Toast, you must use you interface OnItemClickListener to notify your activity when item tapped. For that your activity must implements this interface and the onItemClick method:

```
public class CardListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    ....
    void onItemClick(Card card) {
         Toast.makeText(mContext, "epaepa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("LogDiaViewHolder","epaepa");
    }
}
```

To launch the onItemClick event in adapter you must pass to the adapter an instance of your interface

```
public class CardAdapter extends ListAdapter<Card, CardAdapter.CardHolder> {
    //....
    private OnItemClickListener mListener

    protected CardAdapter(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
        this.mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

and then call the interface method when item click

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 mListener.onItemClick(v)
            }
        });
```